# How to recompile referenced static lib with preprocessor defines from current project in visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have 2 small projects in a vs solution: app and lib.

`app` has a dependency on `lib`. This is specified via "Reference".
`lib` is a static library.

Here is lib source:

a.h:

```
#pragma once
namespace lib{
    void a();
#ifdef UNIT
    void aa();
#endif
}
```

a.cpp:

```
#include <a.h>

void lib::a() { }

#ifdef UNIT
void lib::aa() { }
#endif
```

Here is app source:

```
#include <a.h>

void f()
{
    lib::a();
#ifdef UNIT
    lib::bb();
#endif
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

Here is how solution explorer looks:

[image]

Being a develeoper I would like to specify preprocessor defines in `app` and trigger `lib` recompilation with these defines. In this particular case `UNIT`.

I have a very simple need for that.
When used in unit tests, `lib` should provide different implementation.

When I fully rebuild `app`, linker outputs a linkage error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: lib, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>a.cpp
1>lib.vcxproj -> C:\test\static-lib\Release\lib.lib
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: app, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>app.cpp
2>C:\test\static-lib\app\app.cpp(14,10): error C2039: 'bb': is not a member of 'lib'
2>C:\test\static-lib\lib\include\a.h(2): message : see declaration of 'lib'
2>C:\test\static-lib\app\app.cpp(14,12): error C3861: 'bb': identifier not found
2>Done building project "app.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
Build has been canceled.
Build time 00:00:04.082
Build ended at 4/8/2020 4:04:34 PM
```

From which I conclude that `lib` is recompiled WITHOUT `UNIT`.

This is a very basic thing of a build system and somehow I cannot get it to work.
Is there something I'm missing? I would be grateful for comments.

Comment: That's not a linker error, it's a compiler error.

Comment: Presumably there's a typo above, you seem to have `aa` and `bb` mixed up.

Comment: `I would like to specify preprocessor defines in app and trigger lib recompilation with these defines. In this particular case UNIT` I don't believe that is possible (easily) in visual studio. It would make more sense to specify the defines in a lib header file. That way any code which includes the header file will get rebuilt.

Comment: @john, yes I mixed up aa and bb. the link error is:

`
2>C:\test\static-lib\Release\app.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
2>Done building project "app.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
Build has been canceled.
Build time 00:00:02.584
Build ended at 4/9/2020 9:57:59 AM
`

Comment: @dmytro.poliarush "_the link error is: ` 2>C:\test\static-lib\Release\app.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 2>Done building project "app.vcxproj" -- FAILED. Build has been canceled._" This is not the full error message. Please copy-paste the full error message into the question. Full error message will contain the information about which external symbol was unresolved.

Comment: sorry. Comments are limited to 600 symbols:

`
1>------ Build started: Project: app, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>app.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl lib::aa(void)" (?aa@lib@@YAXXZ)
1>C:\test\static-lib\Release\app.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "app.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
Build has been canceled.
Build time 00:00:01.310
Build ended at 4/9/2020 10:50:26 AM
`

Comment: @dmytro.poliarush I don't understend why you want to do that. Compile full librairy by removing `#ifdef UNIT` from `a.h` and `a.cpp` and test ONLY on your APP. at APP level, test if UNIT is defined, and decide to call  or no `lib::bb();`